# can't install rosbag package

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial
ROS Kinetic

Linux novice, ROS novice.

Have a catkin workspace with some packages in it (robot_localization etc).

```
import rosbag
```

gives error

```
import error: no module named rosbag
```

so tried installing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-rosbag
```

get error:

```
p@t:~$ sudo apt-get install python-rosbag
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-rosbag : Depends: python-roslib but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do? How do i fix the import error?

**Edit**
I'm sorry. I've been at this for months now. I didn't study for this. Frustration is making me go crazy.

$ which python returns "/usr/bin/python" now. I assume this is what it's supposed to be?
$ grep -i anaconda /home/pieter/.bashrc returns "grep: /home/pieter.bashrc: No such file or directory" if that's still relevant

$ ~/folderimworkingin python file.py now returns with error ending in

```
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 83, in get_msg_file
    % (base_type, package, search_path), base_type, package, search_path)
genmsg.msg_loader.MsgNotFound: Cannot locate message [Header]: unknown package [std_msgs] on search path [{}]
```

So am I missing a message package now or?

**Edit**

```
pieter@turing:~/benchmarking$ rospack find std_msgs
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/std_msgs
```

Seems reasonable.

```
>>> import std_msgs
>>>
```

does not complain.

```
Python --version
```

returns 2.7.12 now (instead of 2.7.14).

File.py:

```
#import numpy as np
#import scipy.io
from bag import get_topic_data
testfile = "/home/pieter/benchmarking/bagfiles/2018-03-03-11-13-48.bag"
testdata = get_topic_data(testfile,"/android/imu")
#size = len(testdata)
#print(size)
```

with bag.py:

```
import rosbag
def get_topic_data(bagFile, topic):
    all_msg = []        
    # Initialize rosbag object
    bag = rosbag.Bag(bagFile)        
    for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=[topic]):            
        all_msg = np.append(all_msg, msg)    
    return all_msg
```

bag file I think is accessible?:

```
https://github.com/PieterVanB/bagfile
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284267/can%27t-install-rosbag-package/) by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-03-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-04**:\

> This is all greek to me.

I sympathise with you, but please refrain from making these types of comments.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-05**:
@OperationCrossbow: did fixing the bag fix the issues you were having with your script?

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-03-05**:
@gvdhoorn installed the bagfixer, did catkin_make. source bashed, new terminal. says can't find "fix_bag_msg_def.py" even though it's executable and in the same folder as the input bag. But i'm googlin'.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-05**:
It's not a catkin package, so `catkin_make` is not needed.

You only need to clone the repository, go to the directory where your bag is and then do something like:

```
$ /path/to/where/bag_fixer/is/fix_bag_msg_def.py [...] out.bag
$ rosbag reindex out.bag
```

That's it.

[...] is the other args.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-06**:
Btw: to run programs/scripts in the *current directory*, always prefix the name of the script or program with `./`. Otherwise `bash` will not be able to find the program (unless it's on the path).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
@OperationCrossbow: any luck?

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-03-09**:
@gvdhoorn pieter@turing:~/benchmarking/bagfiles$ /catkin_ws/src/rosbag_fixer/fix_bag_msg_def.py --use-local-defs 2018-03-03-11-13-48.bag out.bag

returns:
bash: /catkin_ws/src/rosbag_fixer/fix_bag_msg_def.py: No such file or directory

What am I missing?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-09**:
You're specifying an [absolute path](https://www.linux.com/blog/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix). That starts at the root of your file system and looks for a directory `catkin_ws` in the root, instead of in your home directory. That won't work.

You can either prefix with the path to ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-09**:
.. your home directory, or use a relative path.

The following should work:

```
/home/pieter/catkin_ws/src/rosbag_fixer/fix_bag_msg_def.py --use-local-defs 2018-03-03-11-13-48.bag out.bag
```

provided you are in the `/home/pieter/benchmarking/bagfiles` directory, of course.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-09**:
But note again that there is no need to place the `rosbag_fixer` directory in your `catkin_ws`. It's not a Catkin package.

Be sure to have `source`d the appropriate `setup.bash` btw. Either the one from your workspace, or the one in `/opt/ros`.

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-03-09**:
@gvdhoorn d'oh. The bag fixer worked!

Trying to launch my file.py throws up "genmsg.msg_loader.MsgNotFound: Cannot locate message [Header]: unknown package [std_msgs]" again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-09**:
That is the exact same error message as before. Are you using `out.bag` now? It doesn't touch the original bag, so you'll have to work with `out.bag`.

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-03-10**:
@gvdhoorn I am not a smart person.. It seems to work now though. Barring a "no module named scipy.io" error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-10**:
That would seem to be a different issue, and with your script, not with the infrastructure any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit 9:

I've updated the tool and ran your bag through it as follows:

```
$ fix_bag_msg_def.py --use-local-defs 2018-03-03-11-13-48.bag out.bag
$ rosbag reindex out.bag
```

This replaced 6 message definitions for me. Afterwards the bag was usable. I have tested your script and I now get errors about `np` not being defined (which is not imported, so that error makes sense).

See the readme of [gavanderhoorn/rosbag_fixer](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/rosbag_fixer) for some more information on how to use it.

---

Edit 8: ok. I believe I know what is going on.

Overview of your situation:

1. your initial problem ("cannot install `rosbag`") was solved/a non-problem: it was already installed, and `python-rosbag` is not actually the pkg you want to install on Ubuntu if you already have `ros-kinetic-rosbag`.
2. the "cannot import rosbag" problem was also solved/worked-around: you were using Anaconda, and the binary packages distributed via the official OSRF package repositories do not support that (the modules are installed in the 'regular' location, and Anaconda doesn't pick those up). You can later try and get Anaconda to work again.

Now as to your latest edit: you didn't mention it (I didn't ask, and I should've), but you're trying to load a bag with messages published by `rosjava` (ROS Java is used by ROS Android under the hood). There is a known issue with `rosjava` that prevents this from working.

For some references, see [ros/common_msgs#20](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/issues/20) and [rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap#16](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/issues/16) (and #q108956, a related question). Note the error message included in the comments on the first issue, it's virtually identical to yours. The problem is described in [rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap#16](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/issues/16):

> It appears that published messages are missing the message definition for the child types which is used for message introspection

In a nutshell this means that `rosbag` has no way of figuring out what the *format* of the data is you're trying to load from your bag, and thus cannot continue processing it. Hence the exception. Looking at your script however it appears to be ok, and should work with just about any bag file that doesn't contain messages published by `rosjava`.

So to summarise: everything is ok now, it's just that you've run into an issue with `rosjava` that prevents your script from *working* (note: this is different from the script being syntactically ok and the runtime environment being able to load all required libraries, as was the problem before).

I've ran into this issue myself, and wrote a simple tool to try and fix bags that contain messages published by `rosjava`: [gavanderhoorn/rosbag_fixer](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/rosbag_fixer). I can't guarantee it will work and it's rather underdocumented (I only needed it once). If you can provide your bag I'm willing to try and fix it for you. Afterwards I'll update my answer with the steps needed to fix arbitrary bags so you can do it yourself if you need to -- I can't remember them now.

(note: I placed my latest edit at the top of my answer, instead of at the end)

---

Can you tell us how you installed ROS?

The reason you cannot get `python-rosbag` to install is most likely because it is not part of the official OSRF repositories, but is distributed as an [upstream package](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages) in Debian (and then imported into Ubuntu). These packages *conflict* with the OSRF packages, and that is why `python-roslib` will not be installed (and thus neither `python-rosbag`).

The following command installs the package from the OSRF repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rosbag
```

The situation with the upstreamed packages and the official packages is unfortunate, but something you will have to keep in mind. As explained on the wiki page I linked above, those upstreamed packages can be recognised by the absence of a ROS release code name, which in this case would be `kinetic`.

---

Edit:

> > So is this Anaconda? What is the output of `which python`?
>
> returns: "home/username/anaconda2/bin/python.

Ok. Your issue is not that you can't install `rosbag`: it is already installed. Installing `python-rosbag` would not have helped either.

The issue is that your Anaconda installation does not seem to be aware of this (it uses different search paths, and `rosbag` is not on those). There are numerous threads on ROS Answers about exactly this issue.

It can be made to work, but for now, please try to use the regular Python 2 interpreter installed on your system. If your script works with that, search for some hints on how to get things working with Anaconda using Google: `anaconda site:answers.ros.org`.

Note though that the official binary packages provided by the OSRF repositories will always only target the system (ie: Ubuntu) provided Python interpreter, which for your platform is still the regular Python 2 `python` binary. Working with Anaconda you'll always have to patch things up.

---

Edit 2:

> How does it more accurately describe what the problem is? I'm so novice that I can't even see that.

The problem is not that `rosbag` can't be installed, as it already is.

The problem is that the `import rosbag` is failing, as your Anaconda install doesn't have that Python module, only the regular Python has it.

> Also, that older question is from before my computer wipe, and remains unsolved for me.

Could be, but that problem was most likely also caused by using Anaconda and then not setting it up correctly.

> Also also, what is "the regular Python 2 interpreter" in your words? $ python file.py doesn't work.

So long as `which python` returns `/home/username/anaconda2/bin/python` things won't work. During installation of Anaconda you may have added `/home/username/anaconda2/bin` to your `PATH`, probably by editing `/home/username/.bashrc`. If you did, temporarily undo that change, start a fresh terminal and see whether `which python` returns something different.

As to "the regular Python 2 interpreter": Anaconda is not the official Python 2 runtime environment. For Ubuntu Xenial, that would be the [python2.7 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/python2.7), which you most likely also have installed.

Anaconda is an *alternative interpreter*. It's got some nice properties, but it also confuses a lot of users, especially novices. So much so, that there is some discussion in the ROS community to warn against its usage. See [Should we warn (new) users about difficulties with Python 3 and alternative Python interpreters?](https://discourse.ros.org/t/should-we-warn-new-users-about-difficulties-with-python-3-and-alternative-python-interpreters/3874).

---

Edit 3: just comment that `export PATH=..` for now. Don't set `PYTHONPATH` either.

I would suggest to first see whether the regular Python 2 setup works. Then start getting Anaconda working.

---

Edit 4:

> .bashrc file, commented out the "PATH" things at the bottom.

Good.

> Can you tell me how I "see if python 2 works" and "get Anaconda working"? This is just shy of "You fix this by fixing it" to my brain.

Re: see if python 2 works: what is the output of `which python` now in a fresh shell? If it's no longer your Anaconda installation, then you're probably ok. Try to execute your script. If that doesn't complain, it's almost certainly using the regular Python 2 interpreter which has all the required modules (libraries) installed.

As to getting Anaconda working: I'm not going to help you with that. That may sound unfriendly, but I don't use it, so I'd have to go and install it myself and / or read up on it and try to replicate and fix your issue. There are a lot of Q&As about Anaconda and ROS on this site already, so those should help you.

The gist of the solutions I've seen is to make sure you either install the ROS Python pkgs (such as `rosbag`) into your Anaconda environment (using Anaconda's equivalent of `pip`, or something similar), or add the ROS `dist-packages` and/or `site-packages` directory to Anaconda's `PYTHONPATH`. But again, I'm not an expert, so refer to the Q&As I mentioned.

---

Edit 5:

> As to "fix it yourself", no, that's fair, that's usually what I expect as an engineering answer. I'm not made for this profession.

Please relax, will you? We're already 5 edit deep into this question. I don't believe I'm leaving you to fix this yourself, am I? We all get frustrated every so often, but telling off the people that are trying to help you is not a constructive attitude.

> As to "which python", I forgot to mention, it's still outputting /anaconda2/. I have no idea what's causing it and google is not playing nice.

Please make sure you have started a new terminal after editing your `.bashrc`. If you have done so, please show the output of `grep -i anaconda /home/pieter/.bashrc`.

---

Edit 6:

> $ which python returns "/usr/bin/python" now. I assume this is what it's supposed to be?

yes, for now at least. You're now no longer using Anaconda.

> $ grep -i anaconda /home/pieter/.bashrc returns "grep: /home/pieter.bashrc: No such file or directory" if that's still relevant

Are you sure you typed the correct path? `/home/pieter.bashrc` is not supposed to exist, so that error message would be correct. I would expect `/home/pieter/.bashrc` to exist (note the `/` between `pieter` and `.bashrc`, which is missing in your error message).

> $ ~/folderimworkingin python file.py now returns with error ending in

> ```
> File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 83, in get_msg_file
> ```

```
    % (base_type, package, search_path), base_type, package, search_path)
genmsg.msg_loader.MsgNotFound: Cannot locate message [Header]: unknown package [std_msgs] on search path [{}]
```

> So am I missing a message package now or?

That is one of the causes of this error message, but seeing as `std_msgs` is such a basic package, I cannot believe that you would not have it. If `rospack find std_msgs` outputs a reasonable path, then I'm not sure what is going on.

If you just start `python` itself, then type `import std_msgs`, does that complain as well?

---

Edit 7: it's strange that importing manually works, and the `std_msgs` pkg is actually found.

Could you add the code of `file.py` to your question? Perhaps something is missing there.

Just occured to me btw: what is the output of `python --version` now?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-03-03**:
How I installed ROS and the current packages I own is in 4 hours time with several USB-stick reboots and complete wipes of my computer, with a doctorate student sitting next to me telling me what to do. Idk what upstreamed packages are.

Also: "ros-kinetic-rosbag is already the newest version".

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-03**:\

> How I installed ROS and the current packages I own is in 4 hours time with several USB-stick reboots and complete wipes of my computer, with a doctorate student sitting next to me telling me what to do

A link to a tutorial would have sufficed.

And Linux != ROS.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-03**:\

> Also: "ros-kinetic-rosbag is already the newest version".

That is ok. It means you already have that package, which is expected.

What is the output of `python --version`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-03**:\

> Idk what upstreamed packages are.

that is why I linked you to the article on the wiki that explains it.

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-03-03**:
@gvdhoorn Ah, sorry. My frustration is getting the better of me. Python is 2.7.14. The doctorate student (my thesis copromotor) told me this is probably the best to use (like Anaconda 2) because it's more stable, works better with ROS, etc, etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-03**:
So is this Anaconda? What is the output of `which python`? If you already have `ros-kinetic-rosbag`, there should be files under `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag`. You did `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`?

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-03-03**:
(1) returns: "home/username/anaconda2/bin/python."
(2) yes, rosbag is there
(3) Yes; there is source /opt/~~/setup.bash is in my bashrc file, so everytime I open a new terminal it should source this.

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-03-03**:
@gvdhoorn still feel like helping me?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-03**:
I edited my answer about an hour ago.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-03**:
Btw: your deleted question (#q284265) more accurately describes what the problem is. And #q281035 seems to be a similar issue with Anaconda.

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-03-03**:
@gvdhoorn How does it more accurately describe what the problem is? I'm so novice that I can't even see that. Also, that older question is from before my computer wipe, and remained unsolved. Also also, what is "the regular Python 2 interpreter" in your words? $ python file.py doesn't work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-03**:
Btw: if your thesis supervisor advised / helped you to install Anaconda, he may also know how to (temporarily) undo the changes to your `PATH`.

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2020-08-06**:
"your initial problem ("cannot install rosbag") was solved/a non-problem:".... really where??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-07**:
`ros-kinetic-rosbag` was already installed. The problem of the OP was never `rosbag` related, it was the `.bag` file.

Additionally, he/she had Anaconda installed and active, which caused problems as `rosbag` is not installed in/for Anaconda, but for the system-default Python interpreter only.